# NServiceBus 4.0 Oracle Persistence without nHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, saga

Is it possible to swap out the default RavenDB implementation for Saga, Subscription and timeouts with an Oracle implementation that isn't dependent on NHibernate.

I'm trying to introduce NSB into an environment where NHibernate isn't already used, and need to keep the stack as basic as possible.

Comment: Why is it relevant how NServiceBus stores its data? Developers won't have to use NHibernate directly.

Comment: Its still a supported component, and if it were to throw an exception for some reason, someone would need to understand NHB enough t o troubleshoot it.  For my shop, its more maintainable without NHB in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own implementations of the persistence interfaces.